# Jquery click event doesn't show button anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, input

I'm using two query click events to dynamically add and delete input fields. This used to work perfectly and now al of a sudden it doesn't. I really can't find the problem

Here is the code

```
<div>
        <input type="image" id="btnAdd" src="~/Images/button_add.png" />
        <input type="image" id="btnDel" src="~/Images/button_remove.png"/>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $aantal = 0;
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; 
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1);      

        var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

        newElem.children(':eq(0)').children(':eq(0)').attr('id', 'check' + newNum).attr('name', 'check' + newNum).attr('checked', false).val('');
        newElem.children(':eq(0)').children(':eq(2)').attr('id', 'extra' + newNum).attr('name', 'extra' + newNum).css({ "background-color": "white" }).val('');
        newElem.children(':eq(1)').children(':eq(0)').attr('id', 'checkVerplicht' + newNum).attr('name', 'checkVerplicht' + newNum).attr('checked', false).val('');

        if (newNum <= 6) {
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
            $('#inputCheck' + num).after(newElemCheck);
        }

        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#btnDel').show();
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; 
        var priceNum = $('.clonedInput').length;
        $('#input' + num).remove();     
        $('#inputCheck' + num).remove();

        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);

        if (num - 1 == 1) {
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#btnDel').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#btnDel').hide();

});
```

The btnAdd works fine, but the btnDel doesn't. When I click the add button, the delete button is supposed to be showed, so the added fields can also be deleted (until there is only 1 field left and the delete button is hided again). This used to work fine, I can't understand why it's not working anymore.

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: newElemCheck is not defined ` at line `$('#inputCheck' + num).after(newElemCheck);`. Look at the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing a variable "newElemCheck" that isn't defined anywhere in the code that you posted. Either this needs to exist in the global namespace or you need to create it (and assign whatever you intended to reference) in the btnAdd click function.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to delete the reference to "newElemCheck".

Answer (score 0):

Use on :

```
$(document).on('click','#btnDel',function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; 
        var priceNum = $('.clonedInput').length;
        $('#input' + num).remove();     
        $('#inputCheck' + num).remove();

        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);

        if (num - 1 == 1) {
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#btnDel').hide();
        }
    });
```

Than use the .on() method to delegate the click event to future elements added to the DOM

Comment: BTW it is same as saying `$('#btnDel').click(function(){..})`. The proper syntax for delegation is `$(document).on('click','#btnDel',function(){})`. You can use any static parent selector at the place of `$(document)`.

Comment: Mritunjay is correct. The .click() function is merely an alias for .on('click', ...). Shorthand basically, but it's perfectly valid.